# Use search and replace to move contents outside of curly braced command (Vim)

Tags: regex, search, vim, sed

I have commands like this:

```
\bold{Foo Bar}
\bold{Foo Bars}
\bold{Foos Bar}
....
\bold{Zoo Cars}
```

and I want to turn them into

```
Foo Bar
Foo Bars
Foos Bar
...
Zoo Cars
```

`:%s/\bold{*}//gc` does not even find any matches. How do I do this?

Note: I googled all around but none of the searches helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing a regexp, but you think it's a glob. You're also not providing a replacement at all. Try `:%s/\\bold{\(.*\)}/\1/gc`.

Comment: I suck at regular expressions and I hate them for it. I didn't give you enough info so the command didn't work for me (I can have more text on a line). So I just changed it to `:%s/\\bold{\([^}]*\)}/\1/gc`

Comment: @puk - `I suck at regular expressions and I hate them for it` In the future, regex will be mixed with normal text processing functions. What are you going to do then?

Comment: @sln: Oh dear, I hope not. And I'm saying that as someone who's been using regular expressions for years (and is currently wearing [this shirt](http://store.xkcd.com/xkcd/#RegularExpressionsShirt)).

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - It will be, its inevitable, the power is too awsome to ignore. It won't just be in script, it's libraries will be integrated in every language. Take a look at Perl 6 for a preview.

Comment: I just can't wrap my brain around a command like this `(?-imsx:(?<!=[\'"])(?<=[*\')+.,;:!&\$\s>])(\()?([\w]+?://(?:[\w\\x80-\\xff#%~/?@\[\]-]|[\'*(+.,;:!=&\$](?![\b\)]|(\))?([\s]|$))|(?(1)\)(?![\s<.,;:]|$)|\)))+))`

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - One more thing. I do find that the immense power of integrated regex, can somehow be retarded in development heirechy by a negative outlook, on sites like this. Regex is an extremely robust feature of native text processing functions. Its inconceiavable the normal engine can be naturally duplicated without it.

Comment: @puk - `just can't wrap my brain around a command like this` even if I told you what it is, or how to format it, and fix errors in it, you still wouldn't understand a basic regex.

Comment: @sln I already mentioned that I don't understand regex, there is no need to be rude

Answer (score 3):

change the delimiter searches, swapping bar by comma. Easy view

```
%s,\\bold{\([^}]*\)},\1,g

whole file .............. %
swap .................... s
, ....................... delimiter search
\\bold{ ................. literal \bold{
\( ...................... open group one
[^}]* ................... all except }
\) ...................... close group one
, ....................... open swap (close search)
\1 ...................... back reference to group one
, ....................... close swap
g ....................... global
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it 2 ways (at least)

(you need to escape the '\' char in front of bold)

1. my recommendation, do it in 2 passes

   ```
   %s/\\bold{/gc 
   %s/}//gc
   ```
2. if  you want to do it all at once

   ```
   %s/\\bold{\(.*\)}/\1/
   ```

Also, do you really need the 'gc' at the end? Not so based on your sample data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The 'c' I always throw in there because I like to inspect it then confirm for 'A'll. 'g' in this example u are right is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are already a lot of answers, but I really don't like to struggle with VIM's substitutions, I always use the `global` and `normal`command for tasks this:

`:g/^\\bold/normal df{f}x`

The `g/^\\bold/` selects the lines that starts with `\bold` and the `normal` tells VIM to run the following instructions in the normal mode: `df{f}x`. Which means:

- `df{` = Delete until you find an {;
- `f}` = Mode the cursor to the next };
- `x`= Removes the } under the cursor;